# How to call __init_subclass__ method after class creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I have the next code:

```py
class A(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        print(f"{name} __new__ 1")
        klass = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        print(f"{name} __new__ 2")

        klass.DEFAULT_VALUE = 1
        return klass


class B(metaclass=A):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.DEFAULT_VALUE = 0
        print(f"{cls.__name__} __init_subclass__")

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(name)


class C(B):
    pass


print(f"DEFAULT VALUE: {C.DEFAULT_VALUE}")
```

when executed it we will see the following text:

```
B __new__ 1
B __new__ 2
C __new__ 1
C __init_subclass__
C __new__ 2
DEFAULT VALUE: 1
```

Here you can see that the call to `__init_subclass__` occurred before the formation of the class based on the A metaclass was completed.
This means that I cannot change the behavior of subclasses if this behavior is defined in the metaclass.

Is there any way to change this cpython behavior without changing metaclass A logic (this behavior is described in the documentations https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object)?

Comment: it doesn't seem likely you'd be able to change cpython behavior without modifying the source code, right? and that might have all kinds of unintended consequences. maybe instead describe a bit more about what you're trying to do. a very basic rebuttal: why would you define behavior in the metaclass, and alter it in the subclasses? instead of specifying the behavior in the subclasses, presuming it's slightly different behavior for each subclass?

Comment: `A.__new__` doesn't create a class; it *causes* a class to be created by calling `super().__new__`. The only thing that can actually create a class is `type.__new__`, which is built into the implementation.

Comment: yes, I certainly simplified the task to a minimum. Actually, I have a class defined in an external library that has a metaclass defined. I want to inherit from this class several other classes and save through a call to `__init_subclass__` the values of some fields that are defined by the metaclass. but since the call to `__init_subclass__` happens before the metaclass has defined those fields, I can't access them from `__init_subclass__ `

Comment: The main purpose of `__init_subclass__` is to *avoid* the need for a custom metaclass in the first place by providing a hook that previously could only be implemented using meta classes.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is simple: instead of setting the class attribute *after* `super().__new__` returns, pass the attribute in the dict passed *to* `super().__new__`.

```
class A(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        print(f"{name} __new__ 1")
        attrs['DEFAULT_VALUE'] = 1
        klass = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        print(f"{name} __new__ 2")

        return klass
```

Now changes made by `__init_subclass__` will still occur before `A.__new__` returns, but *after* the `klass.DEFAULT_VALUE` has been initialized.

As a general rule, the less you make use of custom metaclasses, the better. `__init_subclass__` was introduced as a way of customizing classes *without* needing a custom metaclass in the first place.

Comment: But if don't I have access to class A?

Comment: Then you are out of luck. It's `type.__new__` that actually invokes `__init_subclass__`